# Where do I get SECRET_KEY for Flask?

Tags: python, flask

While trying to set up `Flask-Debugtoolbar`, I am getting:

> "DebugToolBar requires a SECRET_KEY".

Where do I get `SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: Important to note: you should generate the secret key _once_ and then copy/paste the value into your application or store it as an environment variable. Do NOT regenerate the secret key within the application, or you will get a new value for each instance of the application, which [can cause issues when you deploy to production](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30984622/625840) since each instance of the application has a different `SECRET_KEY` value.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The *secret key* is needed to keep the client-side sessions secure. You can generate some random key as below:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(24)
'\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'
```

Just take that key and copy/paste it into your config file

```
SECRET_KEY = '\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'
```

See [Sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions) documentation

Comment: In python 3, if you prefer a plain string (to store in a JSON file, for example), you can convert to a hex string: `import os; print(os.urandom(24).hex())`

Comment: Could you just do `SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)`? I believe this generates a new key everytime, but would that be a problem?

Comment: My above question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287391/why-not-generate-the-secret-key-every-time-flask-starts).

Comment: for the really lazy people like me, here is @Daniel Waltrips line which you can copy paste into command line : `python -c "import os; print(os.urandom(24).hex())"`

Comment: @erncyp or `python -c "print(__import__('os').urandom(24).hex())"`

Comment: @HS-nebula if application generates new random key on every startup then whenever you restart your app or server then each and every session will be destroyed and all the clients will need to login again in case of login is maintained in session

Answer (score 157):

### Get the random string for secret key:

*Method 1:* Use `os` in Python 2/3:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(12)
'\xf0?a\x9a\\\xff\xd4;\x0c\xcbHi'
```

*Method 2:* Use `uuid` in Python 2/3:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'3d6f45a5fc12445dbac2f59c3b6c7cb1'
```

*Method 3:* Use `secrets` in Python >= 3.6:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
'Drmhze6EPcv0fN_81Bj-nA'
>>> secrets.token_hex(16)
'8f42a73054b1749f8f58848be5e6502c'
```

*Method 4:* Use `os` in Python 3:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(12).hex()
'f3cfe9ed8fae309f02079dbf'
```

### Set secret key in Flask

*Method 1:* Use `app.secret_key`:

```
app.secret_key = 'the random string'
```

*Method 2:* Use `app.config`:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'the random string'
```

*Method 3:* Put it in your config file:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'the random string'
```

Then load the config form config file:

```
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')  # if your config file's name is config.py
```

Comment: Should secret key be the same for my Flask application, or should I generate a new one for each user?

Comment: It's used for your application, not the user.

Comment: When using the ´secrets´ module, check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Answer (score 16):

In order to use session in flask you need to set the secret key in your application settings.
secret key is a random key used to encrypt your cookies and save send them to the browser.

This error is because of [this line in the Flask-Debugtoolbar code](https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar/blob/master/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py#L69)

To fix this you just need to set a `SECRET_KEY` in your config file.

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Your_secret_string"
```

or if you have a config file just add below config to it:

```
SECRET_KEY = "Your_secret_string"
```

Answer (score 10):

Open Python, run following in you

```
import secrets
secret_key = secrets.token_hex(16)
# example output, secret_key = 000d88cd9d90036ebdd237eb6b0db000
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secret_key
```

Comment: You should not do that. It would mean that every time you restart application there will be new secret. And this would mean that cookie signature will be different, ergo - session will not prevail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to store Flask's secret_key in a hidden file instead of the code:

```py
import secrets
from pathlib import Path

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET_FILE_PATH = Path(".flask_secret")
try:
    with SECRET_FILE_PATH.open("r") as secret_file:
        app.secret_key = secret_file.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Let's create a cryptographically secure code in that file
    with SECRET_FILE_PATH.open("w") as secret_file:
        app.secret_key = secrets.token_hex(32)
        secret_file.write(app.secret_key)
```

It's always a good idea to store secrets away from versioned code. Git is very good at not losing data. This includes secret keys and passwords :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/#SECRET_KEY), you can use the following command to generate the value of `SECRET_KEY`:

```bash
python -c 'import secrets; print(secrets.token_hex())'
```

It is important to keep in mind the following:

> Do not reveal the secret key when posting questions or committing code.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to hash it with bcrypt hash and use hex

```py
# IMPORT
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import secrets

secret_key = secrets.token_hex(16) #Create HEX Key
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app) #Init Bcrypt
secret_key_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(secret_key) #hash the HEX key with Bcrypt
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secret_key_hash #setup secret key

# Output like: $2b$12$Y0QMIGwksa5OhtOBF9BczuAJ0hYMUv7esEBgMMdAuJ4V.7stwxT9e
```