# Flask Dance to trigger a POST request as redirect

Tags: flask, google-oauth, flask-dance

I am using Flask dance google auth in my Flask app. If a login required is triggered, I am able to redirect the user to the original page that they requested from which a login was triggered. Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752794/17523021

Now, the question is, let's say a Login was triggered by a POST request (form submit) then how to trigger the same form submit once the user is Logged in and redirected to the page that contains form.

I tried finding the solution from docs and stack overflow but couldn't find the answer.