# How to generate HS256 secret key in Python & Flask-JWT-Extended?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I am creating a login system and using Flask-JWT-Extended in my project. However, when I wanted to create a HS256 secret key to encode my JWT, I couldn't find any proper way to do this. Is there any suitable way to do this in Python, Flask? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the configuration options in the flask app

```py
# Example from flask-jwt-extended docs
app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "super-secret"  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

you can also add the config option `JWT_ALGORITHM` e.g.

```py
app.config["JWT_ALGORITHM"] = "HS256"
```

The rest of the [basic usage tutorial](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/) will show you how to actually create the token.

See docs for this config option and others [here](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#JWT_ALGORITHM)

Comment: Thanks. But how does this 'super-secret' come about? What would you recommend if I want to generate random?

Comment: A good answer for this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433731/8903959