# What would happen to Flask sessions if the secret key changed?

Tags: session, cookies, flask, redis, flask-session

Also: What would happen if the actual session data is kept in server side sessions using https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/, e.g. on Redis? (Only a session ID is in the cookie)

The cookie would be of course invalid, from Flasks perspective. Does it delete the cookie automatically? Does [Flask Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/)
 also delete the corresponding Redis entry?

---- EDIT: (upon marked as duplicated):-----

I'm sorry but i assume that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287391/why-not-generating-the-secret-key-every-time-flask-application-starts) is not exactly duplicate. I knew the referenced question before. Unfortunately it does not answer how the internal sessions are invalidated and whether server side sessions are invalidated accordingly by the referenced [Flask Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) library. The other question does not consider any behaviour for **server side** session invalidation.

Also, the other questions seems to propose changing the key, which i do not. Although the necessity might ensue in case of a key leak. In that case it might be interesting what **in detail** happens to client side cookies + server side sessions.