# Flask - Application/Request Context and Sessions

Tags: python, flask, session, heroku

***Introduction***

Hello,

I have a web application where the frontend makes a request to the backend and the backend responds by setting a cookie on the browser (for a session). In addition, a CSRF token is attached to the header of the response.

---

***Problem***

Once the initial request is complete, the browser has the cookie set and the CSRF token is present in the frontend. I would at times get a response from the backend that says the CSRF session token is missing. I thought that was strange since in the network tab of the developers tools, I saw the cookie and CSRF token in the request.

---

***Investigation***

I have previously read [this article on Flask contexts](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-contexts-advanced/) and I'd figure this might have some information that relates to the problem I'm experiencing.

Based on my current setup, I have the following:

- Web server: Heroku
- WSGI server: Gunicorn
- REST API: Flask application

My WSGI server spawns 2 workers (Flask application) to handle all the requests coming in from the frontend.

***Code that handles CSRF protection endpoint***

```
@app.route('/get-csrf', methods=['GET'])
def get_csrf():
    token = generate_csrf() 
    ...
    response.headers.set('X-CSRFToken', token)
    return response
```

***Code for generate_csrf***

```
def generate_csrf(secret_key=None, token_key=None):
    """Generate a CSRF token. The token is cached for a request, so multiple
    calls to this function will generate the same token.

    During testing, it might be useful to access the signed token in
    ``g.csrf_token`` and the raw token in ``session['csrf_token']``.

    :param secret_key: Used to securely sign the token. Default is
        ``WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY`` or ``SECRET_KEY``.
    :param token_key: Key where token is stored in session for comparison.
        Default is ``WTF_CSRF_FIELD_NAME`` or ``'csrf_token'``.
    """

    secret_key = _get_config(
        secret_key,
        "WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY",
        current_app.secret_key,
        message="A secret key is required to use CSRF.",
    )
    field_name = _get_config(
        token_key,
        "WTF_CSRF_FIELD_NAME",
        "csrf_token",
        message="A field name is required to use CSRF.",
    )

    if field_name not in g:
        s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(secret_key, salt="wtf-csrf-token")

        if field_name not in session:
            session[field_name] = hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(64)).hexdigest()

        try:
            token = s.dumps(session[field_name])
        except TypeError:
            session[field_name] = hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(64)).hexdigest()
            token = s.dumps(session[field_name])

        setattr(g, field_name, token)

    return g.get(field_name)
```

My understanding is that once the `/get-csrf` endpoint is handled, Flask will create an application context (and request context) which:

> Keeps track of the application-level data (configuration variables, logger, database connection)

The application context can then be accessed through the `g` and `current_app` proxies.

Then once the request is complete, those contexts are then destroyed.

Within the function `generate_csrf`, a session is created and then `g` is assigned the value of the CSRF token. My understanding is that `g` will only be available for the lifetime of the request and then it's gone. That is fine for the purposes of generating a token.

However, the main issue (to me) is `session` within the request context. The documentation doesn't really explain much how it works.

For example, in `generate_csrf` a session is created, then a token is stored in `g`. After the request is complete, `g` is basically gone. ***But what happens to `session`?***

Below are some logs I have in production:

```
[9] [DEBUG] GET /get-csrf

[10] [DEBUG] POST /login-session
[10] [DEBUG] session cookie sent
[10] [DEBUG] field_name: csrf_token
[10] [INFO] The CSRF session token is missing.

[9] [DEBUG] POST /login-session
[9] [DEBUG] session cookie sent
[9] [DEBUG] field_name: csrf_token
[9] [DEBUG] Session key: csrf_token
```

From above [9] and [10] represents two separate workers. The CSRF token is generated from [9] and session cookie is sent to browser. Then the next request at `/login-session` gets handled by [10]. However, here the session is not available. After a second request, [9] handles it and the session is present.

***This leads me to believe that sessions are stored per worker.*** How would one work around this?

***Update - May 4, 2022***

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27287455/3100570) and then I realized that I had something similar to the following in my code:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') + os.urandom(50)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I presume that each time a worker is spawned, the previous secret the worker used is now invalid.

I updated my secret key configuration to the following:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

It *seems* to have fixed it, but I still need to verify this.